# How to chain two Fetch API requests with Async/Await

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, fetch

I couldn't figure it out for a while... (I am new to React and still learning)

There are two APIs I need to use:

First one contains all clients orders info

{ "orders": [{ "id": "480cb439", "name": "Order Name", "clientId": 4 }, ... ] }

Second one returns client info based on parameter <client_Id> from first API

{ "client": { "id": 4, "name": "John Doe" } }

The goal is pretty simple - fetch info from both APIs, render it into a simple card containing info about both order and client.How to do this with async/await in React using hooks?

My code is below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useApi } from "./services/UseAPI";
import { Loading } from "./components/LoadingComponent";
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button, CardHeader } from 'reactstrap';



function App() {

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
  const handleChange = event => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };

  const Clients = ({clientId}) => {
  const url = `Clients API endpoint` + clientId;
  const param = "client";
  const { data, isLoading, hasError } = useApi(url, [], param);
  
  if (isLoading) return <Loading />;

  if (hasError)
    return (
    <div>
      <p>Failed to fetch worker info </p>
    </div>
    );

  if (data.name !== undefined && data.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()))
    return ( 
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-7 my-auto text-left">
          <div>{data.name}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    else return null;
  }

  const Orders = () => {
    const url = `Orders API endpoint`;
    const param = "orders";
    const { data, isLoading, hasError } = useApi(url, [], param);
    
    if (isLoading) return <Loading />;

    if (hasError)
      return (
      <div>
        <p>Failed to fetch work orders </p>
      </div>
      );
      return ( 
        data.map(order => 
            <div className="col-6">
              <Card key={order.id} className="text-center m-5">
                <CardHeader tag="h5">{order.name}</CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <Clients clientId={order.clientId} searchTerm={searchTerm}  />
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </div>
          )
      );
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <input className="col-10 offset-1" type="text" placeholder="Filter by client name..." value={searchTerm} onChange={handleChange} /> 
      <Orders />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My custom hook for fetching from API:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useApi = (initialUrl, initialData, param) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState(initialData);

  useEffect(() => {
    let unmounted = false;

    const handleFetchResponse = response => {
      if (unmounted) return initialData;

      setHasError(!response.ok);
      setIsLoading(false);
      return response.ok && response.json ? response.json() : initialData;
    };

    const fetchData = () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      return fetch(url)
        .then(handleFetchResponse)
        .catch(handleFetchResponse);
    };

    if (initialUrl && !unmounted)
      fetchData().then(data => !unmounted && setFetchedData(data[param]));

    return () => {
      unmounted = true;
    };
  }, [url]);

  return { isLoading, hasError, setUrl, data: fetchedData };
};
```

Comment: Can the calls be made in parallel or does the second call depend on information in the response of the first one?

Comment: Second call depends on the info from first one...

Answer (score 1):

How about going in more easy way first to make the logic work and then trying to extract the code to custom Hooks. Try the below code, make some necessary adjustments and see if you get the results you expect.

```
  function App() {

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = event => 
  {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };

  const Clients = ({clientId}) => 
  {
  const url = `Clients API endpoint` + clientId;
  const param = "client";
  
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)


  const fetchApiData = async () =>
  {
      setIsLoading(true)
      try 
      {
        const response = await fetch(url)
        const responseJson = response.json
        setData(responseJson)
        setIsLoading(false)
      } 
      catch (error) 
      {
        setError(error)
      }        
  }

    useEffect(() =>
    {
      fetchApiData()
    }, [])
  
  if (isLoading) return <Loading />;

  if (hasError)
    return (
    <div>
      <p>Failed to fetch worker info </p>
    </div>
    );

  if (data.name !== undefined && data.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()))
    return ( 
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-7 my-auto text-left">
          <div>{data.name}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    else return null;
  }

  const Orders = () => {
    const url = `Orders API endpoint`;
    const param = "orders";


    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    const [hasError, setError] = useState(false)
  
  
    const fetchApiData = async () =>
    {
        setIsLoading(true)
        try 
        {
          const response = await fetch(url)
          const responseJson = response.json
          setData(responseJson)
          setIsLoading(false)
        } 
        catch (error) 
        {
          setError(error)
        }        
    }
  
      useEffect(() =>
      {
        fetchApiData()
      }, [])





    
    if (isLoading) return <Loading />;

    if (hasError)
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Failed to fetch work orders </p>
      </div>
      );


      return ( 
        data.map(order => 
            <div className="col-6">
              <Card key={order.id} className="text-center m-5">
                <CardHeader tag="h5">{order.name}</CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <Clients clientId={order.clientId} searchTerm={searchTerm}  />
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </div>
          )
      );
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <input className="col-10 offset-1" type="text" placeholder="Filter by client name..." value={searchTerm} onChange={handleChange} /> 
      <Orders />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you! But my question is more about how to do this with async/await? Like here https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/handling-nested-http-requests-using-the-fetch-api ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with async/await with try/catch block. Try this and see if it works